How to have Docker execute a shell script that writes into .bashrc and have that read at shell startup
I have been trying so many ways to extend the PATH envvar in my container.
Here is my currently last shot at it:
CMD ["echo", "source /opt/ros/jazzy/setup.bash", ">>","/home/$USERNAME/.bashrc", "&&", "/bin/bash", "-l"]

But that source... line simply won't show up in my .bashrc. Is this an entirely wrong approach?

You should normally use the Dockerfile ENV directive to set environment variables.  This can only set individual KEY=value variables, but if you just need to change $PATH, that's often the right path.
ENV PATH=/opt/ros/bin:$PATH
CMD ["main_program"]

If you need to set variables via a script, the best path to do that is to use an entrypoint wrapper script.  As your image's ENTRYPOINT, write a script that does whatever first-time setup needs to be done, then use the shell invocation exec "$@" to switch to the image's CMD (or a run-time override).  source isn't a standard shell command and it can cause problems (for example, on Alpine-based images) but the standard . can read in an auxiliary script in the current shell environment.
#!/bin/sh
# entrypoint.sh

. /opt/ros/jazzy/setup.bash
exec "$@"

# Dockerfile
COPY entrypoint.sh ./
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]  # must be JSON-array syntax
CMD ["main_program"]

Most paths to running things in Dockerfiles don't run shells or read shell dotfiles, so trying to modify dotfiles like .bashrc frequently doesn't have an effect.  In the form you show in the question, the JSON-array exec form of CMD doesn't run a shell; the only thing the container runs is echo(1), passing it arguments including literal strings >> and &&.  The entrypoint wrapper script will run every time you docker run a container, including cases where you're launching a temporary container with a debugging shell instead of its normal main process.
